# Mass rename folders in Win 7

Tags: windows-7, batch

Suppose a folder named 1234-xyz. I would like to rename this folder to xyz - 123. I have a ton of these folders, so going through them one by one doesn't make sense. What is the best way to do this? I am using windows 7. A solution where I won't have to install a new software would be most preferable.

Comment: May be this: http://www.howtogeek.com/111859/how-to-batch-rename-files-in-windows-4-ways-to-rename-multiple-files/

Comment: I use Bulk Rename Utility for bulk renaming of my music files after ripping with WMP (removing the track number from in front of MP3s).  It does folders as well.  I love it enough that I actually donated to the author/programmer.  It may be found here: http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php

Comment: +1 to BRU. Regex support with live previews.

Answer (score 0):

As you have said, you have a lot of folders to rename, and as there is no native batch renaming capabilities built into Windows 7, try using program called "Métamorphose"
You just select the files/folders you want, set the conditions for how you want to name them, then hit go. 
If there are some folders that don't work to the conditions, it flags them and then gives you a list of them after the rest have been renamed, so that you can rename them manually. This cuts down a significant amount of work.

Hopefully this gets the job done for you!

You can download the program Here: http://file-folder-ren.sourceforge.net/